# Implementing a View for filtered search using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filtering, aggregation, searchkick

I am creating a search app using ElasticSearch and Searchkick. Everything works great, but I am having a hard time implementing the view for faceted (aggregated) results. Ex. I have a 100 materials, 20 of which are categorized as "aluminum", 80 of which are categorized as "copper". In my views, I would like to checkmark a "aluminum" filter, and only see the aluminum results. Then I can "un-checkmark" the filter and see all of the results again. How do I go about doing this? Here is what I have been able to hack up, but doesn't exactly do what I want. It simply just re-sets the query to whatever key you've hit.

```
#controller.rb
def index
  query = params[:query].presence || '*'
  @materials = Material.search query, aggs: [:section, :cat_1, :cat_2, :cat_3]
end

#index.haml
.col-md-4
  .col-md-12
    - if @material.aggs.present?
      - if @material.aggs["section"]["buckets"].count > 1
        .widget
          %h4 Filter by Section
            - @materials.aggs["section"]["buckets"].each do |filter|
              .list-group
                = link_to "/materials?query=#{filter["key"]}", :class => "list-group-item list-group-item-action" do
                  = filter["key"]
                  %span.badge
                    = filter["doc_count"]
```